# "If" statement inside of Asymptote function

Tags: asymptote

I want to plot the function `f(x,y)=cos(y)sin(x)/x` even when `x=0` (the function is continuous at such points). I can create a function in Asymptote that plots this surface with `triple f(pair t) {return (t.x,t.y,cos(t.y)*sin(t.x)/t.x);}` that works fine as long as the plotted points never have `t.x=0`. However, I do want to plot such points, and I tried to skirt this issue by using an `if` statement in the definition of the function: when `t.x=0`, I want the function to just return `cos(y)`.

I tried:

```
triple f(pair t) {return (t.x,t.y, if(t.x==0) {cos(t.y);} else {cos(t.y)*sin(t.x)/t.x;});}
```

along with various permutations of existence of `;` and placements of `{}` and `()`; I also tried

```
triple f(pair t) {return if(t.x==0) {(t.x,t.y,cos(t.y);} 
else {(t.x,t.y,cos(t.y)*sin(t.x)/t.x);};}
```

also with various placements of `;`, etc. All I get is a vague `syntax error` message.

How do I combine functions and `if` statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
triple f(pair t)
{
    if (t.x == 0) { return (t.x, t.y, cos(t.y)); }
    return (t.x, t.y, cos(t.y)*sin(t.x)/t.x);
}
```

or

```
triple f(pair t)
{
    return (t.x, t.y, t.x==0 ? cos(t.y) : cos(t.y)*sin(t.x)/t.x);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I just didn't quite understand the syntax of functions as to properly incorporate the `if` statement.